# Android Application in GooglePlay is not visible from China

Tags: android, google-play

I have a question about Chinese googlePlay store. I have published my application more then one week ago - it's visible in my Polish googlePlay account but I got information that it can't be found inside the China ( Shanghai). It's designed for the China fairs... I have checked it to be in all countries ...
The direct link is not working or the app can't be found by it's name.
Is there any way to make it visible ( it's free ).

Regards
Jan

Comment: Contact Google support, not StackOverflow.

Comment: I did it. But Perhaps some of you had this issue before and know what is going on.